# wxPython - Formatting breaks when I add buttons

Tags: python, formatting, modal-dialog, wxpython

So I have a simple modal window that has a few lines of text, an input box, and a couple buttons (save and cancel.) However, the window shows up mostly empty, with the buttons visible but clipped by the edge of the window. But when I comment out the buttons, everything else shows up fine. I can't figure out what's wrong with my buttons, and am hoping some extra eyes will do me some good. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    # Add explanation text
    vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="By default, the sensors record data each minute."), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)
    vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="You can change the recording interval here."), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
    vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="(Should be between 1 and 60 minutes)"), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
    # Make a horizontal line
    line = wx.StaticLine(panel)
    vbox.Add(line, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border=7)
    # Create input
    self.interval_input = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value=self.interval, min=1, max=60)
    vbox.Add(self.interval_input, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    # Make a horizontal line
    line = wx.StaticLine(panel)
    vbox.Add(line, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border=7)
    # Add save and cancel buttons
    button_area = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.save_button = wx.Button(self, label='Save')
    self.save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave)
    button_area.Add(self.save_button, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=5)
    self.cancel_button = wx.Button(self, label='Cancel')
    self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel)
    button_area.Add(self.cancel_button)
    vbox.Add(button_area, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
    # Adjust window size to fit content
    panel.SetSizer(vbox)
    vbox.Fit(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a "parenting" problem. The buttons do not have the same parent as the rest of the widgets, which ends up causing them to get stacked up in a weird way. Change the save and cancel button's parents to `panel` instead of `self` and it will work correctly.

Here's a runnable version:

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test')

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # Add explanation text
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="By default, the sensors record data each minute."), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="You can change the recording interval here."), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="(Should be between 1 and 60 minutes)"), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        # Make a horizontal line
        line = wx.StaticLine(panel)
        vbox.Add(line, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border=7)
        # Create input
        self.interval_input = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="", min=1, max=60)
        vbox.Add(self.interval_input, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        # Make a horizontal line
        line = wx.StaticLine(panel)
        vbox.Add(line, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border=7)
        # Add save and cancel buttons
        button_area = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.save_button = wx.Button(panel, label='Save')
        self.save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave)
        button_area.Add(self.save_button, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(panel, label='Cancel')
        self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel)
        button_area.Add(self.cancel_button)
        vbox.Add(button_area, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        # Adjust window size to fit content
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        #vbox.Fit(self)

        self.Show()

    def OnSave(self, event):
        pass

    def OnCancel(self, event):
        pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you!